# Taking a string, and parsing/tokenizing into smaller strings using hyphen delimiter

Tags: c, string, delimiter, strtok

I am tasked with writing a C program that will take a string with hyphens in it, and check to see that the first group of the string (before the hyphen) is alphabet/letter only, the next group is numeric only, and the last group is alphabet/letter only. It is similar to this project: http://wps.aw.com/wps/media/objects/7257/7431666/Case_Studies/GaddisJavaCSO_CS6.pdf

So far I am stuck on splitting the string into 3 variables. I have read about `strtok` and manipulating the `scanf` function, but I haven't been successful:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
char serial [50];
char * part1 = NULL, part2 = NULL, part3 = NULL;
    printf("Enter Serial Number:\n");
    scanf("%s", serial);
 part1 = strtok (serial, "-");

 part2 = strtok(NULL, "-");
 part3 = strtok(NULL, "-");

    printf("You entered %s\n", part1);
    printf("You entered %s\n", part2);
    printf("You entered %s\n", part3);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The '*' is not part of the datatype, i think you want to write 'char * part1 = NULL, * part2 = NULL, * part3 = NULL;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using strtok wrong, pass parameters to it and it should work fine.

```
char * pch = strtok (serial, "-" );
while (pch != NULL)
{
  printf ("%s\n",pch);
  pch = strtok (NULL, "-");
}
```

or in your example you need to define each as a char* :

```
   char * part1= strtok (serial, "-");
   char * part2 = strtok(NULL, "-");
   char* part3 = strtok(NULL, "-")
```

[StrTok + example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

Comment: Dory Zidon - your strtok use worked for splitting the first group, but I'm getting nonportable pointer conversion errors for the 2nd/3rd group. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Nixneuxs - you need to define each poat as a char* otherwise it is a char and not a char *...either how I show in the edited example or using a pointer notation in front of each var..

Answer (score 0):

```
strcpy(part1, strtok(serial, "-"));//premise: string has hyphen
strcpy(part2, strtok(NULL, "-"));
strcpy(part3, strtok(NULL, "-"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize `scanf`'s formatting rules to read your strings directly from the input line.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char part1[40], part2[40], part3[40];
    int count, n;
    do{
        n = 0;
        flushall();
        printf("Enter Serial Number:\n");
        count = scanf(" %39[A-Za-z]-%39[0-9]-%39[A-Za-z]%n", part1, part2, part3, &n);
        if( count != 3 || n == 0 ){
            printf("Recognize %i parts, %s\n", count, n == 0 ? "did not parse to the end" : "parsed to the end");
        }
    }while(count != 3 || n == 0);

    printf("You entered %s\n", part1);
    printf("You entered %s\n", part2);
    printf("You entered %s\n", part3);
return 0;
}
```

This is quite a strict form of parsing the input and requires the user to keep the outer form. You can easily filter allowed strings by not using `%s` but rather something like `%[0-9]`. The best way for me to filter serialnumber inputs was always Regex if available... but i dont think this is part of your homework yet :)

Comment: yea that sounds super advanced lol. and it seems like you defined each part of the key to have 40 characters...  thank you so much for the response and giving me a hint for a future assignment. I've seen that Regex mentioned a lot of times trying to narrow down an answer before starting a new thread

Comment: Limiting the string is a security thing. You could overflow the string buffer otherwise since scanf has no means of measuring the size of the buffer behind the char pointer. You can also use this to limit the size of the parts. If you want to fiddle a bit with regex you can use an online regex tester like this one: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx